# Keep getting "AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append' "when I run my for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I try to avoid using nested for loops where possible but for this project I'm doing, it seems to be necessary.

I need to run values for computing an angle under Snell's law for a range of incident angles. Further more, I need to do these over a range of refractive indexs.

```
n_list = np.array([1,1.5,2])
theta_i = np.arange(0,90.0,1.0)


angles = []
for i,j in enumerate(n_list):
    for m,n in enumerate(theta_i):  
        angles = np.degrees(np.arcsin(n_list[i]*np.sin(theta_i[m])/n_list[i+1]))
        angles.append(angles)
    print angles
```

But it returns

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Anyone know how I can change the dtype to fix this?

Comment: Stop trying to use the `angles` variable for two things at the same time.

Comment: You're reassigning the output of `np.degrees` to the `angles` var so it's overwriting the list you're attempting to append to.

Comment: Oy vey, I'm a moron! Thanks for the help. All fixed now